Keras metrics are aggregated over training?
Most TF keras models I see are implemented where at the end of a training step they calculate some metric and use metric.update_state(metric_value) to log the metric.
As far as I can understand this doesn't simply overwrite the previous result, but aggregates it in some metric-dependent way it with all the previous results. So if your metric is the Mean subclass, your new metric score will be averaged over all the previous scores. This doesn't seem right? The code below shows what I mean.
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Sum, Mean

m = Mean()
m.update_state(5)
print(m.result()) # 5
m.update_state(2) 
print(m.result()) # (5+2)/2 = 3.5 
m.update_state([1, 2])
print(m.result()) # (3.5+(1+2)/2)/2 = 2.5

m = Sum()
m.update_state(5)
print(m.result()) # 5
m.update_state(2) 
print(m.result()) # 5+2 = 7
m.update_state([1, 2])
print(m.result()) # 7 + (1+2) = 10


Ok I think I understand now–answering for anyone else confused. Keras metrics are "stateful metrics" which means they accumulate results over training and they need to be explicitly reset. This is for flexibility, so you can accumulate across batches and then reset at each epoch end.
According to this you need to list any metrics you want reset every epoch in your model class definition:
    @property
    def metrics(self):
        # We list our `Metric` objects here so that `reset_states()` can be
        # called automatically at the start of each epoch
        # or at the start of `evaluate()`.
        return [self.loss_tracker, self.mae_metric]


